# "Rewrite" a type

Tags: types, coq

I have the following Coq code:

```
Set Implicit Arguments.

Record eq {X : Set} (R : X -> X -> Prop) : Set := 
  mkEq {
    reflexivity: forall x, R x x
}.

Record eqSet : Type := 
  make {
    set : Set;
    r : set -> set -> Prop;
    r_eq : eq r
}.

Definition Nat : eqSet.
  refine (make (set:=nat) (r := fun x y => x = y) _).
  apply mkEq.
  auto.
Defined.

Lemma ex : forall (x : set Nat) (P : nat -> Prop), P x.
  intro.
```

The lemma "ex" is just an example of what I want to do. After the final "intro", I have in my hypothesis:

```
x : set Nat
```

I would like to replace "set Nat" by "nat". (the tactic "trivial" already proves "set Nat = nat"). Is it possible?

Comment: You can `simpl in *`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that `x` is used in the goal, so changing its type might also affect the typing of your goal. If you perform

```
  assert (h: set Nat = nat) by now trivial.
  revert x.
  rewrite h.
```

You'll have a typing error.

I'm not sure how to do this nicely.

V.